# Direct message a user by id - not in async form

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a coding class that I wish to use a discord.js v12.5.1 d example to send a message to a user.

So far, I have the following code from [inhoLee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358108/in-discord-js-can-i-send-directmessage-to-user-with-discordbot)'s question's answers:

```
client.once('ready', () => {
client.users.get("userid").send("test");
}
```

And the following is my list of dependencies, as it matters:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed, Message } = require('discord.js');
Discord.Constants.DefaultOptions.ws.properties.$browser = 'Discord Windows';
const { keep_alive } = require('./keep_alive');
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./config.json');
const CatLoggr = require('cat-loggr');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const log = new CatLoggr();
var request = require('request');
```

It would be preferable if the answers were not in an async/await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=users) is a [`UserManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/UserManager) that contains cached [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User)s.
[`UserManager.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/UserManager?scrollTo=cache) is a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection), which is the key-value cache.
[`Collection.has(userid)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=has) checks if the cache has the user with the specified id.
[`UserManager.createDM(userid)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/UserManager?scrollTo=createDM) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that resolves to the created [`DMChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/DMChannel).
[`DMChannel.send(msg)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=send) will send a message in the [`DMChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/DMChannel).

```js
if (client.users.cache.has(/*userid*/)) {
  client.users.createDM(/*userid*/).then((dmchannel) => {
    dmchannel.send("hi i'm a bot");
  });
} else console.log("user not found");
```

This method does use asynchronous programming, but it does not use `async`/`await` as requested.

As far as I have seen there are multiple ways to do this, but this is the method I found after reading the [Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/general/welcome).

Comment: I will test this, but it looks like it works and you will receive the reputation following! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that messages a user by displayName and by numerical id for discord.js v14:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Collection } = require("discord.js");
const { Guilds, GuildPresences } = GatewayIntentBits;

const client = new Client({
  intents: [Guilds, GuildPresences],
});


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  // Get the bot's default Guild
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.first();

  // Get members by displayname
  // const user = guild.members.cache.find(m => m.displayName === `my_display_name`);
  // Get members by user->id
  const user = guild.members.cache.get('numerical_userid');

  console.log(user);

  user.send('your message');
  // console.log(user);
});

client.login('token');
```

A couple notes:

- Your bot and the member must share a server.
- You must have GuildPresences to find all online members.

  > WARNING: This only works correctly if you have the GuildPresences intent enabled for your application and client.
- The guilds.cache returns a collection, but you can use first() to get the first guild object.

Comment: My bot runs on discord v12.5.1 for a specific reason, thanks, but this will not flow in my code.